# How can we fetch url and thumbnail of youtube videos by any query in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, youtube-api

i am trying to develop an android application which get videos from Youtube and show them on grid view but i don't know how can we get video thumbnail and url of youtube videos programmatically with query ? 
Can anybody help me

Comment: To get a thumbnail and an URL, you'll need to specify **from which video** you want them. You'll typically search that by video ID. And that's [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)